# Kubernetes & Terraform: installing to all K8s nodes to prevent ImagePullBackOff

Tags: kubernetes, terraform-provider-kubernetes

[Re: ImagePullBackOff](https://www.tutorialworks.com/kubernetes-imagepullbackoff/) errors: K8s "relies on the fact that images described in a Pod manifest are available across every machine in the cluster" ... and if that assumption is not met you might see ImagePullBackOff.

Just so I am totally clear here (my K8s cluster runs containerd) are these true?

- Once a new image is created, is the correct procedure to install it *to each node in the k8s cluster individually*?
- Is that something the Terraform K8s provider can do? As far as I understand it, Terraform **apply** typically assumes the image is already known to containerd, because something else placed the images onto each node in the k8s cluster already. Terraform **doesn't make the image nor does** terraform place or stage images in containerd for ultimate K8s deploy. Terraform assumes that's already done.

Originally I was thinking one just gives the image to the master K8s node, and then before/during deployment, K8s automagically replicates and installs it everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach is that your images are coming from a registry that is reachable from all nodes, either a public one like Docker Hub or GitHub Packages or a private one hosted locally (sometimes even inside the cluster).

Technically you *could* skip that and manually distribute images to nodes some other way (for example there are some preseeding tools that use BitTorrent for it) but those are generally extremely advanced use cases. Use a normal registry :)

Comment: Good point. Thank you.